# Android comprehensive failproof music service across multiple activities

Tags: android, service, background, andengine, playback

I know this question has been asked many times before and might seem to be a conglomeration of several questions, but I feel that it is relevant and important to many developers; I need to create a background music `Service` that can run across multiple activities for my Android game that ends when the application is terminated and pauses in all of the following circumstances:

1. A certain `Activity` that has its own music is started. (Resume when this `Activity` finishes. This happens to be an `AndEngine` activity.)
2. The home screen is pressed and the app is backgrounded, or the application is terminated. Resumes when the app returns to the foreground. Requires use of [`onUserLeaveHint()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612058/android-onbackpressed-onuserleavehint). [Another helpful link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208912/how-can-i-detect-user-pressing-home-key-in-my-activity)
3. The phone receives a call and interrupts the app. Resumes when the call has been dealt with. Requires use of `TelephonyManager` similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121508/android-taking-complete-control-of-phone-is-it-possible-how).
4. The screen is locked. (Resumes after screen has been unlocked.) Requires use of [`ACTION_USER_PRESENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT), which seems to [be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853494/action-user-present-in-manifest-with-broadcastreceiver) [very](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on) [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601014/can-an-action-user-present-broadcastreceiver-not-be-registered-in-the-manifest).
5. Basically the music pauses whenever the app is not being shown or when the special activity from #1 is being shown to the user.

Above is all of what I need and the information I have pieced together. ***My current code basically resembles [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489889/mediaplay-in-android-musicservices-crashes-when-calling-mediaplayer-pause).***

I find it curious that `AndEngine` manages to have none of these issues with their music, so maybe looking in the source code would help someone looking for an answer. I'm using [the last functional GLES1 version from Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/).

I have taken a look at the following links as well on creating a good music `Service`:

- [Stopping Background Service Music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620758/stopping-background-service-music)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App
- [Android background music service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service)
- [Playing BG Music Across Activities in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097909/playing-bg-music-across-activities-in-android)
- http://www.rbgrn.net/content/307-light-racer-20-days-61-64-completion

I would like the solution `Service` to:

- Minimize the use of `BroadcastReceivers` and Android Manifest additions/permissions if possible
- Self contained and error checking

Other Notes

- Currently all the activities that require the background music all extend a common special class.
- The music needs to loop but only runs a single track.

Thanks to everyone ahead of time! Best of luck!

Edit - Here are code snippets, feel free to improve or ignore:

*Media Player Wrapper*

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class CarefulMediaPlayer {
    final SharedPreferences sp;
    final MediaPlayer mp;
    private boolean isPlaying = false;

    public CarefulMediaPlayer(final MediaPlayer mp, final MusicService ms) {
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ms.getApplicationContext());
        this.mp = mp;
    }

    public void start() {
        if (sp.getBoolean("com.embed.candy.music", true) && !isPlaying) {
            mp.start();
            isPlaying = true;
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        if (isPlaying) {
            mp.pause();
            isPlaying = false;
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        isPlaying = false;
        try {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        } catch (final Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

*Music Service*

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MusicService extends Service {
    static CarefulMediaPlayer mPlayer = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(final Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.title_music);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mPlayer = new CarefulMediaPlayer(mp,this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
        mPlayer.start();
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(final Intent intent, final int startId) {

    }

    public IBinder onUnBind(final Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public static void onStop() {
        mPlayer.stop();
    }

    public static void onPause() {
        if (mPlayer!=null) {
            mPlayer.pause();
        }
    }

    public static void onResume() {
        if (mPlayer!=null) {
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }
}
```

*Improved Base Activity Class*

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public abstract class BetterActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean isHome = true;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        System.gc();
        super.onResume();
        MusicService.onResume();
        isHome = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getCallState()==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING
                || !((PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)).isScreenOn()) {
            MusicService.onPause();
        }
        super.onPause();
        System.gc();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown (final int keyCode, final KeyEvent ke) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            isHome = false;
        default:
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, ke);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startActivity(final Intent i) {
        isHome = false;
        super.startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
        if (isHome) {
            MusicService.onPause();
        }
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm in the process of trying to accomplish all your goals myself and saw your question. Any progress? I'll try to let you know how this goes when I am done.

Comment: @ajacian81 haven't been on the site in a while, we decided to delay the music and release earlier as a beta.

Comment: ok well I'll let you know how my attempt goes, I should have some answers in a month or so.

Comment: That's great, I'll be waiting!

Answer (score 5):

First here is some code. Below I'll give you an explanation.

```
public class MusicService extends Service {

    // service binder
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    // music player controling game music
    private static CarefulMediaPlayer mPlayer = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // load music file and create player
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.title_music);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mPlayer = new CarefulMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    // =========================
    // Player methods
    // =========================
    public void musicStart() {
        mPlayer.start();
    }

    public void musicStop() {
        mPlayer.stop();
    }

    public void musicPause() {
        mPlayer.pause();
    }

    /**
     * Class for clients to access. Because we know this service always runs in
     * the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        MusicService getService() {
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return mBinder;
    }

}
```

Activity:

```
public class StartupActivity extends Activity {

// bounded service
private static MusicService mBoundService;

// whetere service is bounded or not
private boolean mIsBound;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_startup);
    doBindService();

    // HOW TO WORK WITH THE SERVICE:
    // call the following methods whenever
    // you want to interact with you 
    // music player
    // ===================================

    // call this e.g. in onPause() of your Activities
    StartupActivity.getService().musicPause();

    // call this e.g. in onStop() of your Activities
    StartupActivity.getService().musicStop();

    // call this e.g. in onResume() of your Activities
    StartupActivity.getService().musicStart();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    doUnbindService();
}

private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        setService(((MusicService.LocalBinder) service).getService());
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        setService(null);
    }
};

private void doBindService() {
    Intent service = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MusicService.class);
    // start service and bound it
    startService(service);
    bindService(new Intent(this, MusicService.class), mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mIsBound = true;
}

private void doUnbindService() {
    if (mIsBound) {
        // Detach existing connection.
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
        mIsBound = false;
    }
}

public static MusicService getService() {
    return mBoundService;
}

private static void setService(MusicService mBoundService) {
    StartupActivity.mBoundService = mBoundService;
}
}
```

First of all you got a Service which runs in background. This service creates the mediaPlayer object as you did. With the localBinder you can bind the Service in your Activity(ies) and access it like a normal Java-Object. 
The Activity I've posted bindes the Service. In it's onCreate() method you can find a way how to interact with your mediaPlayer.
You can bind any Activity to your Service.

Another Solution:

```
public class CarefulMediaPlayer {
final SharedPreferences sp;
final MediaPlayer mp;
private boolean isPlaying = false;
private static CarefulMediaPlayer instance;

public CarefulMediaPlayer(final MediaPlayer mp, final MusicService ms) {
    sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ms.getApplicationContext());
    this.mp = mp;
    instance = this;
}

public static CarefulMediaPlayer getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public void start() {
    if (sp.getBoolean("com.embed.candy.music", true) && !isPlaying) {
        mp.start();
        isPlaying = true;
    }
}

public void pause() {
    if (isPlaying) {
        mp.pause();
        isPlaying = false;
    }
}

public void stop() {
    isPlaying = false;
    try {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    } catch (final Exception e) {}
}
}
```

Then you can pause, play and stop the music by calling CarefulMediaPlayer.getInstance().play();

Comment: Implement pausing and resuming the MediaPlayer in every single Activty and you are done. Whenever it gets interrupted the music will pause. You can also create a "abstract"-Activity-Class which implements this feature and all your Activities will extend this one. (this is the more elgant version)

Comment: I am getting a null pointer exception on: StartupActivity.getService().musicStart();          Any ideas why this might be null?

Comment: I am also getting null on StartupActivity.getService().musicStart(); anyone have a solution as to why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

I did it this way and I'm pleased with the result:

**1st create the service:**

```
public class LocalService extends Service
{
    // This is the object that receives interactions from clients. See RemoteService for a more complete example.
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private MediaPlayer player;

    /**
     * Class for clients to access. Because we know this service always runs in
     * the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder
    {
        LocalService getService()
        {
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        destroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return mBinder;
    }


    public void play(int res)
    {
        try
        {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, res);
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
            player.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void pause()
    {
        if(null != player && player.isPlaying())
        {
            player.pause();
            player.seekTo(0);
        }
    }


    public void resume()
    {
        try
        {
            if(null != player && !player.isPlaying())
            {
                player.start();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void destroy()
    {
        if(null != player)
        {
            if(player.isPlaying())
            {
                player.stop();
            }

            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }

}
```

**2nd**, create a base activity and extend all your activities in witch you wish to play the background music from it:

```
public class ActivityBase extends Activity
{
    private Context context = ActivityBase.this;
    private final int [] background_sound = { R.raw.azilum_2, R.raw.bg_sound_5 };
    private LocalService mBoundService;
    private boolean mIsBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        doBindService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        try
        {
            if(null != mBoundService)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int what = background_sound[rand.nextInt(background_sound.length)];
                mBoundService.play(what);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        basePause();
    }



    protected void baseResume()
    {
        try
        {
            if(null != mBoundService)
            {
                mBoundService.resume();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    protected void basePause()
    {
        try
        {
            if(null != mBoundService)
            {
                mBoundService.pause();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection()
    {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service)
        {
            // This is called when the connection with the service has been
            // established, giving us the service object we can use to
            // interact with the service. Because we have bound to a explicit
            // service that we know is running in our own process, we can
            // cast its IBinder to a concrete class and directly access it.
            mBoundService = ((LocalService.LocalBinder) service).getService();

            if(null != mBoundService)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int what = background_sound[rand.nextInt(background_sound.length)];
                mBoundService.play(what);
            }
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className)
        {
            // This is called when the connection with the service has been
            // unexpectedly disconnected -- that is, its process crashed.
            // Because it is running in our same process, we should never
            // see this happen.
            mBoundService = null;

            if(null != mBoundService)
            {
                mBoundService.destroy();
            }
        }
    };

    private void doBindService()
    {
        // Establish a connection with the service. We use an explicit
        // class name because we want a specific service implementation that
        // we know will be running in our own process (and thus won't be
        // supporting component replacement by other applications).

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocalService.class);
        bindService(i, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }

    private void doUnbindService()
    {
        if (mIsBound)
        {
            // Detach our existing connection.
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mIsBound = false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        doUnbindService();
    }
}
```

And that's it, now you have background sound in all the activities that are extended from ActivityBase.

You can even control the pause / resume functionality by calling basePause() / baseResume().

Don't forget to declare the service in manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.gga.screaming.speech.LocalService" />
```

Comment: This worked for me with a few modifications to suit my code, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the startup activity we are binding and Starting Service seperately. This is wrong since service will keep running after activity exits as we haven't called **stopService()** anywhere. So The part ' startService(service) ' should be removed as bind service is already "**Auto-Creating**" the service too.

Please correct me if anyone got opposite results

```
startService(service);// remove this part
bindService(new Intent(this, MusicService.class), mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```